# Difference between two functions creating a singleton list

Tags: haskell, hlint

When running hlint over my program it reported an **error** for

```
\x -> [x]
```

and suggested the alternative form

```
(: [])
```

What is there **erroneous** according to hlint about the first form, and thus why should I use the (less readable) second option?

#### Edit

(added hlint explicitly to the question)

My question lies not so much with what the difference is (I do understand both of them) in lexical point of view. My problem is that I do not understand why hlint is marking it as an **error**. Is there for example a difference in laziness? Furthermore why is the previous thought of as **erroneous** by hlint while `\x -> Just x` raises only a warning.

Comment: Yeah `(:[])` ("the robot") is weird for beginners; it certainly tripped me up the first time I saw it.  But now it's just another idiom in my vocabulary -- much like pluralizing a variable name (e.g. `xs`) or using a section to flip a function (e.g. ``(`Map.member` m)``)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A common question, to which I've just added an answer in the [HLint manual](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/darcs/hlint/hlint.htm#error_vs_warning). It says:

> Every hint has a severity level:
>
> - **Error**  - for example `concat (map f x)` suggests `concatMap f x` as an "error" severity hint. From a style point of view, you should always replace a combination of `concat` and `map` with `concatMap`. Note that both expressions are equivalent - HLint is reporting an error in style, not an actual error in the code.
> - **Warning** - for example `x !! 0` suggests `head x` as a "warning" severity hint. Typically `head` is a simpler way of expressing the first element of a list, especially if you are treating the list inductively. However, in the expression `f (x !! 4) (x !! 0) (x !! 7)`, replacing the middle argument with head makes it harder to follow the pattern, and is probably a bad idea. Warning hints are often worthwhile, but should not be applied blindly.
>
> The difference between error and warning is one of personal taste, typically my personal taste. If you already have a well developed sense of Haskell style, you should ignore the difference. If you are a beginner Haskell programmer you may wish to focus on error hints before warning hints.

While the difference is personal taste, sometimes I change my mind. Looking at the two examples in this thread, `(:[])` seems a relatively "complex" hint - you are breaking down the syntactic sugar of `[x]` to `x:[]`, which in some ways is peeling through the abstraction of a list as a generic container, if you never pattern match on it. In contrast `\x -> Just x` to `Just` always seems like a good idea. Therefore, in HLint-1.8.43 (just released) I have made the first a warning, and the second an error.

Answer (score 12):

There is no real difference. HLint concerns itself with style issues; ultimately, they are just hints on how to make your code look better.

In general, using a lambda with a constructor or function like that is redundant and makes the code *harder* to read. As an extreme example, take a constructor like `Just` as an example: compare `Just` to `\ x -> Just x`. These are equivalent but the second version certainly makes things more confusing! As a closer example, most people would choose `(+ 1)` over `\ x -> x + 1`.

In your particular case, it's a different story because lists have special syntax. So if you like the `\ x -> [x]` version better, just keep it. However, once you become used to operator sections, it's likely you'll find the `(: [])` version as easy--if not easier--to read, so consider using it even now.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Though for me still a question remains (which was maybe the most interesting part), why does hlint think it's an error and not a warning? I've edited the question to make this more clear and added the results for running hlint over your example.

Comment: What hlint considers an error and what it considers a warning is just a judgement call from Neil Mitchell.  Don't anything deep into it.

Comment: @augustss, ok when that's the criterium I should indeed not put much weight on the differences between errors and warnings.

Answer (score 7):

I might consider using `return` or `pure` for this:

```
ghci> return 0 :: [Int]
[0]

ghci> import Control.Applicative
ghci> pure 0 :: [Int]
[0]
```

I needed to include the type annotation (`:: [Int]`) because I was working in GHCi. In the middle of a bunch of other code you probably wouldn't need it.

Comment: Though sometimes tempted to do this, I think it makes it less clear what is going on than with either one of the other solutions.

Comment: I still remember the day I worked out that `return :: [x]` is `\ x -> [x]`. I wish Haddock had a good way to document such useful facts...